# Mapping nested types using NEST 1.0

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to create a mapping with a nested type using NEST 1.0. The [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834767/how-can-i-use-nested-types-with-nest-client-for-elastic-search) for this question doesn't work anymore in the latest version of NEST because NestedObject doesn't seem to be part of the API anymore. (This is also noted in a comment on the accepted answer)

Having looked at the [list of breaking changes](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html) with version 1.0 I can't find anything about changes to mapping nested types. And the documentation also doesn't seem to provide an example of such a mapping.

**So how do I create a nested mapping with NEST 1.0?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this fluent syntax in order to perform the mapping of a Nested object. This works and it's tested for NEST up to 1.3.1 (current version 1.4.3).

```
client.CreateIndex(c => c
     .Index(indexName)
     .InitializeUsing(indexSettings)
     .AddMapping<OutterObjectType>(m => m
         .Properties(p => p
             .NestedObject<NestedObjectType>(n => n
                  .Name("NestedObjectName")))));
```